# Socket.io dropping packages?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, network-programming, game-development

I have a game where the server side pushes packets to the client side. Each packet is an action is strictly necessary to rebuild the state on the client-side. (think event sourcing)

I've noticed that some packets are not arriving, but I can't narrow it down exactly.

I was wondering if is possible to detect when the packets are being dropped and to request a fresh new full state from the server-side when this happen.

I'm using sockets.io with node.js and it happens when I run in chrome.

Comment: Is there any in between page refresh or call to init method? In that case it may happen connection get reset